# Derivative of an Inverse Function $f(x)=x^5+2x^3+1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

Is my solution correct?

$f:{\mathbb{R}}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}},f(x)=x^5+2x^3+1$. Show that $f$ has an inverse. Find $(f^{-1})'(49)$.

---

$f'(x)=5x^4+6x^2$

$f'(x)>0$, this means that $f$ has an inverse.

We need $(f^{-1})'(49)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(49)}$.

Find $f^{-1}(49)$

$49=x^5+2x^3+1$

$x=2$

$\Rightarrow f(2)=49$

$\Rightarrow 2=f^{-1}(49)$

$(f^{-1})'(49)=\frac{1}{f'(2)}=\frac{1}{104}$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: this should be just a vote for Ninad's comment.

Comment: Ok. $$$$$$$$$$$$

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)>0$ is not quite correct, since it is not true when $x=0$. Even so, since this only happens at one point (in fact it would be okay as long as this is a set of measure $0$), you can still argue that your function is  strictly increasing, hence one-to-one (which means that your function has an inverse).

Essentially what you are doing is that for $x<y$:
 $$f(y)-f(x)=\int_{x}^y f'(t) dt>0$$

Since $f'(t)>0$ for almost every $t$.

Comment: What do you mean by "strictly continuous"?

Comment: oh, I meant increasing, thanks for the catch.

Comment: te veo por aquí